# Launch specific external application using powerapps in Android

Tags: android, powerapps

Well, I am a newbie in powerapps. Recently I had this task to run an external 
Android application (A type of NFC reader) which is currently not supported on powerapps.

So I researched and understood there is a method for lunching in powerapps:
You can launch a url like this:

```
Launch("https://www.bing.com")
```

You can launch skype like this:

```
Launch("skype:")
```

The syntax is like this:

```
Launch( Address [, ParameterName1, ParameterValue1, ... ] )
```

Address - Required. The address of a webpage or the ID of an app to launch.

ParameterName(s) - Optional. Parameter name.

ParameterValue(s) - Optional. Corresponding parameter values to pass to the app or the webpage.

But how about a specific unknown application?

I want to for example load app at address below in google play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ssaurel.nfcreader&hl=en

I know that I can navigate user to address below, but Is there a way to run application directly?

```
Launch("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ssaurel.nfcreader&hl=en")
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep Links are something that the developer of the app you're trying to open has to explicitly add: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

They'll add something like the following to their app's manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and then you'll be able to `Launch('example://gizmos')` to open the app accordingly. Unfortunately you are not able to link to applications that have not already been configured as above--deep link support is opt-in for the developer.